# Application-defined or object-defined error when copying data between excel workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data between 2 Excel workbooks but I am getting the error:

> Run-time error 1004
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

I don't understand why. Any help with this?

---

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim xWb As Workbook, xWs As Worksheet

Dim yWb As Workbook, yWs As Worksheet

Set xWb = Workbooks("A.xlsm")

Set yWb = Workbooks("B.xlsm")

Set xWs = xWb.Sheets("1")

Set yWs = yWb.Sheets("2")

xWs.Range("DatatoCopy").Value = yWs.Range("Destination").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have sheets named "1" and "2"? Do you have Ranges named "DatatoCopy" and "Destination" defined?

Comment: Did you make sure that there is an Excel file by the name `A.xlsm` and another by the name `B.xlsm` open? Did you make sure that `A.xlsm` has a sheet named `1` in it while the other Excel file has a sheet named `2` in it? Also, please make sure that there is a named range called `DataToCopy` in `A.xlsm` on sheet `1`. Ensure the same for the second named range `Destination` and also make sure that both ranges have the exact same size (rows and columns).

Comment: and also that both the sheets where the name ranges are , are active

Comment: @ApurvPawar - it is neither possible nor necessary for both sheets to be active.

Comment: @SJR they are in two different workbooks, active in the sense selected

Comment: @ApurvPawar - yes fair point about being active but still not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes "" for Sheets("1") make it like Sheets(1)

Comment: It's possible that the OP has sheets named "1" and "2".

Comment: Yes that's correct the sheets are named "1" and "2" so that is not the issue.

Comment: just check all the things what Ralph has mentioned, Its working at my end.